# Some items in my ipod library have a NULL assturl property

Tags: mpmediaitem

When try to pick an item from my ipod library some items play and some dont.
Looking at my log some items have a NULL for assetURL.
Why would that be?

Answer (score 0):

all item are DRM protected  which return null assetURL. You can't access such item

Answer (score 0):

I want to add something to this. There are three reasons that I know of why `assetURL` will be null

1. The item is in the cloud (in which case `isCloudItem` will return true).
2. As stated in another answer, if the track is DRM protected.
3. This is the kicker, tho: in some cases, and item downloaded on the device, which is not DRM, will play in Music (the built-in App), but will still have assetURL returning NULL.

This means that any non-Apple App that uses the MediaPlayer framework may encounter some media items that play in Music, but which cannot be played in the App. Your end user can usually "fix" this problem by deleting the offending track in Music, and downloading it again.

I find that if I download a complete album and see this issue, then downloading the album again (after deleting it) will lead to some different tracks having the problem, so that is not a good way to go.

I have entered an Apple bug-report for this (21477730). I also used a DTS to ask for a work-around: there is none. If you are encountering this too, a "me too" to the bug report. This may increase the chances of a fix.

If you want to try this out for yourself, below is the code that I sent in with the bug report.

```
MPMediaQuery *allAlbumsQuery = [MPMediaQuery albumsQuery];
NSArray *allAlbumsArray = [allAlbumsQuery collections];

for (MPMediaItemCollection *collection in allAlbumsArray)
{

    NSArray* items = collection.items;
    MPMediaItem* rep = collection.representativeItem;
    NSString* name = rep.albumTitle;
    for(MPMediaItem* item in items)
    {
        NSURL* url = item.assetURL;
        BOOL isCloudItem = item.isCloudItem;
        if(!isCloudItem && (url==nil))
        {
            NSString* albumTitle = item.albumTitle;
            NSString* trackTitle = item.title;

            NSLog(@"****Nil: %@ %@",albumTitle,trackTitle);
        }
    }

}
```